Apex method printing empty value sent in from LWC
I never had issues with apex method not receiving any data from LWC.
Here in the below code and writing the WorkOrderIds and VendorNames to one variable split by the pipe operator. This is the sample of the data logged in the browser -
const workOrderIdsAndVendorNames = data.map(workOrder => `${workOrder.Id}|${workOrder.Vendor__r.Name}`);
console.log('workOrderIdsAndVendorNames:', JSON.stringify(workOrderIdsAndVendorNames, null, 2));

Console logged data -
workOrderIdsAndVendorNames: [
  "0WOcp000000AP1xGAG|Vendor 1",
  "0WOcp000000HoWfGAK|Vendor 1",
  "0WOcp000000EhmsGAC|Vendor 1",
  "0WOcp000000AP0LGAW|Vendor 1"
]

Now I am sending the above data to the apex method this way -
this.getFeedsForAllWorkOrders(workOrderIdsAndVendorNames).then(() => {}

Apex Method - The System debug statements print empty values.
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<FeedItem> getFeedsForAllWorkOrders(List<String> workOrderIdsAndVendorNames) {
    System.debug('workOrderIdsAndVendorNames: ' + workOrderIdsAndVendorNames);
    List<String> workOrderIds = new List<String>();
    List<String> vendorNames = new List<String>();

    if (workOrderIdsAndVendorNames != null) {
        for (String item : workOrderIdsAndVendorNames) {
            List<String> splitItem = item.split('\\|');
            if (splitItem.size() == 2) {
                workOrderIds.add(splitItem[0]);
                vendorNames.add(splitItem[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    System.debug('Work Order Ids: ' + workOrderIds);
    System.debug('Vendor Names: ' + vendorNames);

    return [
        SELECT
            Id,
            ParentId,
            Status,
            CreatedById
        FROM FeedItem
        WHERE ParentId IN :workOrderIds
        AND Title IN :vendorNames
        AND Type = 'TextPost'
        ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
        LIMIT 20
    ];
}

This was my previous apex method which worked, it is when I changed it to the above it stopped working.
public static List<FeedItem> getFeedsForAllWorkOrders(List<String> workOrderIds) {
    return [
        SELECT
            Id,
            ParentId,
            Status,
            CreatedById
        FROM FeedItem
        WHERE ParentId IN :workOrderIds
        AND Type = 'TextPost'
        ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
        LIMIT 20
    ];

}

When calling an apex method from lwc, you need to pass in an object of the named arguments, rather than just calling it with the arguments directly.
Additionally, you may not need to use the this when you reference getFeedsForAllWorkOrders. But without knowing your code, I can't know for sure...
So instead of:
this.getFeedsForAllWorkOrders(workOrderIdsAndVendorNames).then(() => {});

Do this!
this.getFeedsForAllWorkOrders({
  workOrderIdsAndVendorNames
}).then(() => {});

But again, you may not need to use this. If you are directly calling the imported apex method, no this needed. If you are wrapping the method call in a method of the lwc class, then you will need this

Sorry that I didn't mention, I have already tried the code you mentioned before posting, but it didn't work. I have added the previous apex method to the post which worked.

@sumchans, I do suggest you try both stackasaur's suggestions again: they sound right to me.

try getFeedsForAllWorkOrders({
workOrderIds: workOrderIdsAndVendorNames
}).then(() => {});

@stackasaur, it was late in the day when I tried your answer. I was not thinking straight. Your answer works. Thanks.
